# Is it possible to use the Smart Capture form on another website?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, website-integration

Is it possible to Integrate Smart Capture form on another website and send data to Data extension

If yes, then How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Create a normal CloudPage with a SmartCapture form and [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) it onto another website.

Or

2. Use the DEManager functionality, which is a Marketing Cloud standard functionality for such use cases - creating forms on external websites and writing form data into a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud:

Here’s the example HTML from the documentation:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="12345" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="WebCollectSubs" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="https://example.com/Success" />
            <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="https://example.com/Failed" />
            Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br />
            First Name: <input type="text" name="FirstName"><br />
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="LastName"><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

where you need to change the web collect URL to https. This example is for the S1 instance. For other instances, replace s# with the instance you are on for "cl.s#.exct.net".

You will also need to update the tags to place information in the data extension.

- _clientID - your account number
- _deExternalKey - the external key for the data extension to receive the subscriber information
- _successURL and _errorURL - the pages shown to the subscriber after they complete the form

More info on DEManager here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_demanager.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

Both options mentioned above have their cons and can be buggy at times, but if you’re not a developer (who could build a proper form on the external website and integrate it via API with Marketing Cloud), then they are the only two you have.